# Is there some better way to create some custom fields in the database by using some Java EE, JPA framework?

Tags: java, jpa, orm, dynamically-generated

We use Oracle ADF platform to build web applications and extend to webcenter portal application.

The current expectation from Java developers team is to change our development approach/method, so that  adding some fields in the application should not required any development effort. In other words, when you want to add a data field (at least no relation to any field) in some form, it should be enough to save some metadata of the field to the database along with execution of related job/commands in the application. Additionally, we need to render the view dynamically according to added fields.

Essentially, I think that such an expectation is not suited for the Java world, but if it could be possible or if someone has prior experience  to do this, I would want to use it. We don't want to be interact directly with the database using native SQL through JDBC, as that would mean going out of the ADF framework.

Comment: What do you intend to do, could you be a bit more specific on what your needs are?

Comment: This is called *custom fields*. Am I right?

Comment: Let me try to explain in another words. Suppose that, we define the metadatas of custom field(s), for example its type(string, number, combobox etc)length, isunique, mandatory... And then we run the execute command of this field definition to create on database and map to related entity object from now on. I assume that might be possible to add entity class as property belonged to class. Anymore when rendering the page, new custom field must be shown in form view if even there is no deployment process...

Comment: Yes Roman C you're right

Comment: EclipseLink supports dynamic attributes on entities in JPA, see, http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Extensible_Entities

Comment: @user1841447, I've reworded your question so that it could be reopened. Please verify if I'm missed out something. If you dont get an answer, start looking into extension points for JPA implementations - James has already pointed out one for EclipseLink. JPA Extension points are not a standard so they'll depend on your ORM provider.

Comment: Yes Vineet, you have described as what i exactly meant. Thank you for your gently guidance. I will read about EclipseLink and what can i do to use in our adf project. Thanks a lot to James

Comment: Has anybody got sample project about used eclipselink extensible entities? I could not find enough detailed docs, i have searched even though pretty much.